# Kendo UI grid should display message as 'no data' for selected in drop down option

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using Kendo UI for the grid. It displays data based on the drop-down option selected.
When it loads the first time I have set the .norecords message as 'Select an option.'
So when some option from the drop-down has no data to display in the grid it shows the same message 'Select an option.' I want to have a message displayed as No data for selected option message but it shows select an option message for dropdown option as 'Select an option' when already option is selected.

Comment: Have you got a minimum, reproducible and working example we can look at?

Comment: Missing examples, code snippets and or reproducability

Answer (score 0):

You should conditionally set the `noRecords.template` based on if the dropdown has a value. Here is an example:

```js
$('#my-dropdown').kendoDropDownList({
  // your dropdown options...
  change: function(e) {
    var value = this.value();
    var noRecordsMessage = (!value ? 'Select an option' : 'No data for selected option');
    var grid = $('#my-grid').data('kendoGrid').setOptions({
      noRecords: {
        template: noRecordsMessage
      }
    });
  }
});
```